# Best practices for handling "NA" when all NA values exist due to being below the limit of detection?

Tags: r, statistics, missing-data, data-imputation

I am working in R, and have a data set which has a few metabolite concentration values as continuous variables. Anywhere that the concentration was too low to be detected it simply says <LOD. This covers ~40% of the data for one metabolite, and 80% of the data for another.

I don't actually currently intend to use these values for anything, but it got me curious about how best to handle these if I did want to use them. For the metabolite missing ~40% of its data, for example, let's call Met1, the limit of detection is a concentration of 0.40.

Naturally the "missingness" here is not random at all since the data is missing due to being low, meaning imputation is likely to introduce significant bias. I could perhaps try a mice-style imputation with a post squeeze to make sure all values are below the 0.40, but as there aren't any values in the data set that *are* below 0.40 for the variable, I can't imagine the imputation would be strong and valid.

I could replace all <LOD with the lowest observable value, 0.40, or some value under the LOD, say 0.00, or split the difference at 0.20. Again, bias would be introduced fairly significantly.

But I don't like the idea of just replacing them with NAs, because they aren't *completely* not available, we *know* the value is lower than 0.40, which is somewhat useful and I hate to "lose" that aspect of the information.

Are there standard or preferred practices for dealing with something like this? I don't necessarily need code or packages suggested, just a statistical principle to read up on!

Comment: To save the data without losing anything you could simply introduce another 0/1 variable `less_than_LOD`, and leave `NA`s in the original sequence.